# convert my string to comma based elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a legacy Rails project that relies on Ruby version 1.8

I have a string looks like this:

```
my_str = "a,b,c"
```

I would like to convert it to

```
value_list = "('a','b','c')"
```

so that I can directly use it in my SQL statement like:

```
"SELECT * from my_table WHERE value IN #{value_list}"
```

I tried:

```
my_str.split(",")
```

but it returns "abc" :(

How to convert it to what I need?

Comment: can't you use some thing like a `where in` in RoR, like `@some_obj = SomeModel.where("somefield in (?)", [1,2,3,4])`?

Comment: I need an answer with precondtion of raw SQL like mentioned in question. Whether using Rails API to filter out is out of the scope of my question due to legacy reasons I just have to use raw SQl difficult to explain why here..

Comment: You can use ActiveRecord's [`quote`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Quoting.html#method-i-quote) to escape the strings yourself.

Answer (score 2):

To split the string you can just do

```
  my_str.split(",")
  => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

The easiest way to use that in a query, is using `where` as follows:

```
  Post.where(value: my_str.split(","))
```

This will just work as expected. But, I understand you want to be able to build the SQL-string yourself, so then you need to do something like

```
  quoted_values_str = my_str.split(",").map{|x| "'#{x}'"}.join(",")
   => "'a','b','c'"
  sql = ""SELECT * from my_table WHERE value IN (#{quoted_values_str})"
```

Note that this is a naive approach: normally you should also escape quotes if they should be contained inside your strings, and makes you vulnerable for sql injection. Using `where` will handle all those edge cases correctly for you.

Comment: The word "safe" might giving of the wrong vibe here. Since I could still drop the database with an input like: `"a,b'); DROP DATABASE x;"`

Comment: Yes, good remark, changed and clarified. Exactly why I proposed to use `where` instead. But maybe the OP is well aware what kind of data the `my_str` can contain.

Answer (score 1):

Under no circumstances should you reinvent the wheel for this. Rails has built-in methods for constructing SQL strings, and you should use them. In this case, you want [`sanitize_sql_for_assignment`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_for_conditions) (aliased to `sanitize_sql`):

```rb
my_str = "a,b,c"

conditions = sanitize_sql(["value IN (?)", my_str.split(",")])
# => value IN ('a','b','c')

query = "SELECT * from my_table WHERE #{conditions}"
```

This will give you the result you want while also protecting you from SQL injection attacks (and other errors related to badly formed SQL).

The correct usage may depend what version of Rails you're using, but this method exists as far back as Rails 2.0 so it will definitely work even with a legacy app; just consult the docs for the version of Rails you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
value_list = "('#{my_str.split(",").join("','")}')"
```

But this is a very bad way to query. You better use:

```
Model.where(value: my_str.split(","))
```

Comment: Tried your answer, it misses the single quotation mark. e.g. `('a','b','c')`

Answer (score 0):

The string can be manipulated directly; there is no need to convert it to an array, modify the array then join the elements.

```
str = "a,b,c"

"(%s)" % str.gsub(/([^,]+)/, "'\\1'")
  #=> "('a','b','c')"
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters other than commas and save to capture group 1. `\\1` retrieves the contents of capture group 1 in the formation of `gsub`'s replacement string.

Answer (score -3):

couple of use cases:

```
  def full_name
    [last_name, first_name].join(' ')
  end
```

or

```
  def address_line
      [address[:country], address[:city], address[:street], address[:zip]].join(', ')
  end
```

Comment: Should you not limit your answer to demonstrate the use of `join`? Why do we need methods? How are these relevant?

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, it might be related to OP's title, but neither of the two methods you have posted bring the OP's input to the desired output (`"a,b,c"` => `"('a','b','c')"`)